# Tricky XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt

Assume an XML tree of label and item pairs, each of which contain mark-up requiring transformation:

```
<list>
   <label>ABC<ptr target="#note-1"/></label>
   <item><ref type="link">123</ref></item>
   <label>DEF<ptr target="#note-2"/></label>
   <item><ref type="link">456</ref></item>
   ...
</list>
```

(N.B., the mark-up inside the `<label>` and `<item>` elements is merely an example. These elements may have an arbitrary amount of mark-up contained within them. So, that nested mark-up will be handled by template rules. Using XSL string functions, etc., to handle this nested mark-up is not an ideal solution since the number of possible tags is large.)

Suppose then the goal is to transform this into an HTML unordered list, like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>ABC<sup>1</sup> <a href="link1.html">123</a></li>
   <li>DEF<sup>2</sup> <a href="link2.html">456</a></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

I've been trying to match the `<label><item>` node pairs with the preceding::sibling axis, e.g.

```
   <xsl:template match="list[@type='index']/item[preceding-sibling::label]" >
    <li><xsl:value-of select="./preceding-sibling::label[1]"/> <xsl:apply-templates/></li>
   </xsl:template>
```

But my output emits the content of `<label`> twice: once before the `<li>` element (properly transformed) and again inside the `<li>` element (without transformation), like this:

```
  <ul>
     ABC<sup>1</sup>
     <li>ABC <a href="link1.html">123</a></li>
     DEF<sup>2</sup>
     <li>DEF <a href="link2.html">456</a></li>
     ...
  </ul>
```

I understand that the `<label>` content inside the `<li>` is not being transformed because I am using `<xsl:value-of>`. I'm just trying to illustrate the goal I'm trying to achieve of getting the content of both `<label>` **and** `<item>` inside the `<li>`.

If I add the following template to suppress the second instance of the content from the `<label>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="list[@type='index']/label"></xsl:template>
```

then the redundant set of content from `<label>` is eliminated, but not the right one. E.g.,

```
<ul>
     <li>ABC <a href="link1.html">123</a></li>
     <li>DEF <a href="link2.html">456</a></li>
     ...
  </ul>
```

So, my question is, how do I get the content from `<label>` and `<item>` into a single `<li>` element, while at the same time having that content processed by other templates in my stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

**This is quite straightforward to do in XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="list">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="label"/>
  </ul>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="label">
  <li>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>

   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select=
       "substring-after(ptr/@target, '#note-')"/>
   <sup>
     <xsl:value-of select="$vPos"/>
   </sup>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "following-sibling::*[1][self::item]">
    <xsl:with-param name="pPos" select="$vPos"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:param name="pPos"/>
   <a href="{@type}{$pPos}.html">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be wellformed):

```
<list>
   <label>ABC<ptr target="#note-1"/></label>
   <item><ref type="link">123</ref></item>
   <label>DEF<ptr target="#note-2"/></label>
   <item><ref type="link">456</ref></item>
</list>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ul>
   <li>ABC<sup>1</sup>
      <a href="1.html">123</a>
   </li>
   <li>DEF<sup>2</sup>
      <a href="2.html">456</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Dimitre: Thanks you for your response. I failed to make clear that in addition to the `<ptr>` and `<ref>` elements in the source XML, there are another 20 or so different tags that can possibly appear. The solution you have provided only handles the two tags I used in my example. My goal is to have a more general solution where I could have an arbitrary number of templates match on the content of both `<label>` and `<item>`. However, if necessary, I can use your solution and handle those additional elements with XSLT functions. But I would prefer to rely on templates, since it seems cleaner.

Comment: @sarcanon: Please, edit the question to make it more relevant, or better, accept this answer and ask a new question, letting me know via a comment.